# I am trying to manipulate a dictionary in python so I can just print part of it

Tags: python

```
 for i in sorted (acronyms):
    print(acronyms)
    answer = input("\n would you like to see the whole list? (y or n)")
    if answer == "y":
        print (i, " : ", acronyms[i])
    else:
        param = input("\n enter 0-9 or A-Z to display those entries: ")
        print (i, " : " , acronyms[param])
```

is there a way that I could change it or add another layer of functionality to
print out just a section of the dictionary (ex.  just the A section).  Right now I return an error. I'm sure it is in the way I am calling my parameter, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Can you describe the data structure you're using for the library itself (acronyms)?

Comment: I am using a basic library: acronyms{ k:i}

Comment: Err... your code won't work at all. Why do you have the questions *inside* your for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues here, and your code isn't working for reasons that you don't necessarily expect.

Firstly, the data structure you're using is a dictionary, not a library.

I think the situation is that you have a dictionary like `acronyms={'NASA': 'National Aeronautics and Space Administration', 'ESA': 'European Space Agency', 'JAXA': 'Japan Aerospace Exploration Agency'}`, and you want to give the user the option of printing all the acronyms, or just a portion with certain first letters. If this isn't the case, let me know.

So let's start with your code:

```
for i in sorted (acronyms):
   print(acronyms)
   answer = input("\n would you like to see the whole list? (y or n)")
   if answer == "y":
       print (i, " : ", acronyms[i])
   else:
       param = input("\n enter 0-9 or A-Z to display those entries: ")
       print (i, " : " , acronyms[param])
```

You have the right idea with going through the acronyms with a for loop, but you do it far too early. You want to loop through in order to print the acronyms, but in order to do that, you need to know what the user wants *first*. And I think that `print(acronyms)` is probably there from your debugging. But let's move back, first, to just figuring out how to print out the list. If we just want to print the whole list, it's pretty easy. We'll loop through, and use your print statement:

```
for i in sorted(acronyms):
    print(i, " : ", acronyms[i])
```

But some comments here: don't put spaces between functions and their arguments. It's bad form in Python. Also, when asking questions, be sure to note whether you're using Python 2 or 3: most people use 2, while it seems you're using 3, which makes many incompatible changes to things like print.

Now, what if we have a `param` here, and only want to print acronyms starting with that? The obvious thing to do is to add a conditional when going through:

```
for i in sorted(acronyms):
    if i[0]==param: print(i, " : ", acronyms[i])
```

Alternatively, we could start out with our list of all acronyms `alist = sorted(acronyms)`, and then filter it with a list comprehension: `alist = [ x for x in alist if x[0]==param]`. This will also let us make our code more compact and less redundant.

Now let's add back in the input. We'll ask the user what they want to print, then we'll filter the list, use that to make our list to loop through, and only then will we loop through and print:

```
answer = input("\n would you like to see the whole list? (y or n)")
if answer == 'y':
    alist = sorted(acronyms)
else: 
    # You really should check for 'n', though, 
    # and have an else that gives an error otherwise.
    param = input("\n enter 0-9 or A-Z to display those entries: ")
    alist = [ x for x in sorted(acronyms) if x[0] == param ]

for i in alist:
    print(i, " : ", acronyms[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be confusing real world dictionaries and Python dictionaries.

In Python, a dictionary has a *unique* key, to which is assigned a value. Your code doesn't seem to fit this, because you would have multiple entries under each letter?

Comment: Yeah, I got a little confused at the time.  I apologize

Comment: @user4859850 not to worry! The other answer was much better than mine:)